# New pandas data frame at given index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `pandas` data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = np.arange(1, 53)
quantities = np.arange(1, 53)
data = dict(quantities=quantities)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=data.keys(), index=timestamps)
df.rename_axis('timestamps', inplace=True)
```

I'm trying to get change the data frame to different values:

```
timestamps_new = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
df = df.loc[timestamps_new]
```

This works, but I get the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

**Why does this happen?** I also get a KeyError when I use:

```
df = df.loc[timestamps_new, 'index']
```

or

```
df = df.loc[timestamps_new, 'timestamps']
```

Thanks for any help understanding this.

Comment: It's not an error, just a `FutureWarning`. You can suppress them: `import warnings;
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)`

Comment: also, `loc` is failing because you do not have a column with name `index` or `timestamps`. Try `df.loc[timestamps_new, 'quantities']`

Comment: @ChrisA What if you want all columns, rather than just `quantities`?

Comment: then just `df.loc[timestamps_new]` or `df.loc[timestamps_new, :]` will do

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks. Both options still raise the warning though.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777951/how-to-suppress-pandas-future-warning

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks, though the end of the warning says it'll raise an error in future, so would rather solve, than suppress, the issue.

Comment: Just use the suggestion? `df.reindex(timestamps_new)`

Comment: @ChrisA Yep ... :-/ Thanks

Comment: which version of pandas you are using?. i am using 0.21.0 and i am not getting any warning df = df.loc[timestamps_new]