# "synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'." problem in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I installed TensorFlow 1.10.1 but when I tried to import TensorFlow it said that I need TensorFlow version 1.10.0. Thus, I installed it and now I get the following warnings:

```
>>> import tensorflow
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

Comment: tensorflow 10.1 ? I think you mean 1.10.1

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It just a warning, not an error. It occurring because your current numpy libray version is not compatible with tensorflow version. You need to downgrade numpy version.

`tensorflow 1.10.0` has requirement `numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3`, but you must have some higher version installed(this warning message occurs with newest numpy version 1.17.0).

Comment: What version should I downgrade numpy to?

Comment: BTW what's your current numpy version?

Comment: My numpy version is 1.17.0

Comment: downgrade it to above version

Comment: By the way if you downgrade to 1.16.0 you won't receive warning msg, it occurs in numpy 1.17, but still `tensorflow 1.10.0 is compatible with numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3`

Comment: But when I downgraded to 1.16.0 version its perfectly fine, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, because this warning comes with numpy v1.17.0

Comment: I wouldn't say there is an absolute need to downgrade from v1.17.  Everything here looks like a `FutureWarning` and not an `Error`.  If, like me, code is running properly with only the `FutureWarning` then it may be acceptable to stick with the current version.

Comment: Install older numpy version than 1.17. eg: pip install numpy==1.16.4

Comment: As @user11563547, a `FutureWarning` usually means "your code is working fine, but on a _future_ update might stop working". There is no need to downgrade here.

Answer (score 69):

If you're using TF 2.0 **a quick solution would be to downgrade your numpy** to 1.16.4. (I used 1.17 and received the same warning messages).

```
1. pip uninstall numpy 
2. pip install numpy==1.16.4
```

See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31249) (thanks to ymodak)

Comment: Works for tensorflow-gpu=1.14

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, provides the specific version.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the issue. It's a workaround.

Comment: I also reverted to `numpy==1.16.4` while running CPU `tensorflow==1.14.0` to silence these warnings.

Answer (score 17):

Or, one could just silence the warning:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
import tensorflow as tf
```

This approach was suggested here: [How to suppress Pandas Future warning ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777951/how-to-suppress-pandas-future-warning)

Answer (score 15):

```
pip install "numpy<1.17"
```

To revert to Numpy version *1.16.4*

Comment: 1.16.6 is the latest version

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in my linux laptop with tensorflow in python3 v3.6

Actually, you just need to change some lines in 2 files :

- 1

  ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py

in your case :

```
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py
```

now change this code : (line 516)

```
_np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
_np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
_np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
_np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
_np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])


# _np_bfloat16 is defined by a module import.

# Custom struct dtype for directly-fed ResourceHandles of supported type(s).
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

by this code :

```
_np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, (1,))])
_np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, (1,))])
_np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, (1,))])
_np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, (1,))])
_np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, (1,))])

# _np_bfloat16 is defined by a module import.

# Custom struct dtype for directly-fed ResourceHandles of supported type(s).
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, (1,))])
```

you have to do the same on this file :

- 2

  ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py

in your case :

```
C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\envs\tut\lib\site-packages\tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

The newest numpy release notes (1.17) has:

```
Future Changes

Shape-1 fields in dtypes won’t be collapsed to scalars in a future version
Currently, a field specified as [(name, dtype, 1)] or "1type" is interpreted 
as a scalar field (i.e., the same as [(name, dtype)] or [(name, dtype, ()]). 
This now raises a FutureWarning; in a future version, it will be interpreted 
as a shape-(1,) field, i.e. the same as [(name, dtype, (1,))] or "(1,)type" 
(consistently with [(name, dtype, n)] / "ntype" with n>1, which is already 
equivalent to [(name, dtype, (n,)] / "(n,)type").
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html

Thus with your expression:

```
In [123]: np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])                                                                  
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[123]: dtype([('qint8', 'i1')])

In [124]: np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, (1,))])                                                               
Out[124]: dtype([('qint8', 'i1', (1,))])

In [125]: np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8)])                                                                     
Out[125]: dtype([('qint8', 'i1')])

In [126]: np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 2)])                                                                  
Out[126]: dtype([('qint8', 'i1', (2,))])

In [127]: np.__version__                                                                                     
Out[127]: '1.17.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have multiple versions of numpy installed or have a new numpy version that is not compatible with tensorflow?

```
>pip show numpy
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

Downgrading numpy version from >1.17 to 1.16.4 will resolve issue with Tensorflow 1.14.0

How to downgrade numpy?

```
pip uninstall numpy # (till you uninstall all versions)
pip install numpy==1.16.4
```

After that you can check the copatibility:
After that, please restart your runtime and execute below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of your TensorFlow version is incompatible with numpy. Try reinstalling numpy's previous versions. In my case I tried 1.16.4 :
pip install numpy==1.16.4

But first, you need to shutdown all running kernals and uninstall numpy with : 
pip uninstall numpy