# tensorflow warning for data types

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow and numpy in Python 3.7.4 [64-bit]. When I tried importing it, I get the following warning:

> /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8,
>   1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8",
>   np.uint8, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16",
>   np.int16, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16",
>   np.uint16, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32",
>   np.int32, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   np_resource = np.dtype([("resource",
>   np.ubyte, 1)])
>
> /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8,
>   1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8",
>   np.uint8, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16",
>   np.int16, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16",
>   np.uint16, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32",
>   np.int32, 1)])
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   np_resource = np.dtype([("resource",
>   np.ubyte, 1)])

I have the following versions-
numpy- 1.17.0
tensorflow- 1.14.0

How can I solve the warnings for the different data types in tensorflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'." problem in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381430/synonym-of-type-is-deprecated-in-a-future-version-of-numpy-it-will-be-underst)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it's saying is that to conform to planned changes in `numpy` this line

```
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

will need to be rewritten as

```
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, (1,))])
```

I don't think this is in your own code.

The relevant passage in numpy 1.17 is:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#future-changes

This is a warning, not an error.  In a similar recent SO, the poster got rid of it by switching to an earlier `numpy` version.

["synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'." problem in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381430/synonym-of-type-is-deprecated-in-a-future-version-of-numpy-it-will-be-underst)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to ignore them for now:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

although it does not resolve the root cause.