# How to install the latest version of TensoFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow2.0

I am wondering that why I cannot install the *TensorFlow 2.0.0* (stable version until now [in their official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions) even [in PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/))

I used to had the TensorFlow `2.0.0b1` version, but I was dealing with several warnings because my `numpy` version wasn't compatible with the TensorFlow. It was `1.17` and must be `1.16.4` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381430/synonym-of-type-is-deprecated-in-a-future-version-of-numpy-it-will-be-underst)). Hence, I downgrade it but TensorFlow didn't work anymore. So I decide to reinstall the TensorFlow latest stable version as mentioned above.

Here is I've done so far:

```
pip install -U tensorflow
```

It trow backs `1.14` through `pip show tensorflow`

```
pip install tensorflow
```

It trow backs `1.14` through `pip show tensorflow`

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
pip install 'tensorflow>=2'
```

They trow back the following error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

*OS: Ubuntu 16.04*
*Python: 3.6.8*
*numpy: 1.16.4*
*pip3 version: 18.1*

---

[UPDATE OCT 2020]:

Apparently, this problem has been resolved, because I'm able to install *tensorflow 2.3.1* at the moment without any problem on *Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial*.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support the `manylinux2010` tag and TF 2 dropped support for `manylinux1` (as the glibc version was too old). Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported())"` to verify that - `manylinux2010` is not listed. Update to 18.04 to get the `manylinux2010` support.

Comment: @hoefling Yes, I checked it, that was not. Thanks for the response. So should I use `2.0.0b1` version in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @hoefling And what about `pip install tf-nightly` instead?

Comment: `tf-nightly` is basically a wheel built from current master, so it doesn't support `manylinux1` either since the latest releases don't. With xenial, the last installable version is 2.0.0b1, unfortunately. Surely, you can build tensorflow from source or play with installing a more recent glibc from a PPA, but IMO the easier path to take is to upgrade to bionic (if you can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning the solution in this section (even though it is mentioned in the Comments Section), for the benefit of the community.

Any of the below steps will resolve the issue:

1. Using the `Tensorflow` Version, `2.0.0b1` for the Ubuntu  Version 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)  Or
2. By upgrading the Ubuntu OS Version from `16.04 (Xenial Xerus)` to `18.04 (Bionic Beaver)`, we can install the Latest `Tensorflow Version`.

Comment: Apparently, this problem has been resolved, because I'm able to install *tensorflow 2.3.1* at the moment without any problem on *Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial*.