# Ignoring FutureWarnings in Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, warnings, deprecation-warning

This question is a followup from here: [How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)
I have the following code:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable 
import operator
import calendar
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
    import pandas as pd, datetime, calendar
...
{rest of my code}
```

I am trying to suppress these warning:

```
<ipython-input-3-7e458c7b53b6>:22: FutureWarning: weekofyear and week have been deprecated, please use DatetimeIndex.isocalendar().week instead, which returns a Series.  To exactly reproduce the behavior of week and weekofyear and return an Index, you may call pd.Int64Index(idx.isocalendar().week)
  data['week'] = data.index.week
```

For some reason this is not ignoring these warnings. I am trying to ignore the warning of just in pandas where they are originating from and not the warning which i may get from other packages. Could you please advise as to why this is not working?

Comment: Is it not easier to listen to the warning and stop using deprecated code?

Comment: We didn't go to the  moon because it was easy

Comment: I just want to know how to do it. I will fix the code though but why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my little research, pandas seems to have some tricky way of doing it. have you tried `import warnings;   warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`?

You can also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777951/how-to-suppress-pandas-future-warning). And if the warning persists just let it be, it won't stop your code from running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that would ignore all the warning, not just the warning for pandas since you have not mentioned any packages. I want the warning to just be suppressed for certain packages not others :)

Comment: It alright, have you checked the thread yet? It really said a lot about this issue.

Comment: Neither this nor the thread silenced the warning for me. @JaneDoe I see you have accepted the answer, so how did you exactly solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To only suppress FutureWarning messages:

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```