# Pandas 2.1.0 FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I'm having an issue with Pandas `v2.1.0+` that I can't figure out.

I have a list of columns in my pandas data frame that I need to convert using a custom function.  The new values depend on multiple columns in the data, so I'm using apply to convert the column in-place:

```
my_columns_to_convert = ['col1','col2','col3']

for k in my_columns_to_convert:
  df[k] = df[[k,colx]].apply(lambda x: convert_my_data(value_1_in=x[0],value_2_in=x[1]),axis=1)
```

This has worked just fine in previous versions of pandas. But now I get:

```
FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
```

But I'm not using loc or iloc, and everything I've reviewed thus far seems to point at that being the issue.  How can i write this code so that I'm doing it the 'correct' way in the future?

Using previous methods in Pandas that did work.

Comment: You said "I'm not using loc or iloc", and that's exactly what the warning is telling you to do. Maybe using `x.loc[0]` instead of `x[0]` will get rid of the warning (I'm not sure). Maybe the issue is with the `colx` object. Could you include it in your post?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with an input dataset (as code) and the definition of a dummy `convert_my_data` function, not forgetting the matching expected output.

Comment: If you got this warning using a module that uses pandas in the backend, such as `statsmodels.tsa`, unless you don't want to make a PR yourself, there's nothing you can do until the devs update the source code. Well, I guess you could suppress the warning; [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15777951/19123103) might help in that regard.

Answer (score 6):

This `FutureWarning` can be triggered in [`2.1.0`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v2.1.0) with this simple example :

```
ser = pd.Series({"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c"})

# A    a
# B    b
# C    c
# dtype: object

print(ser[1]) # gives 'b' but with a FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys..
```

The goal is to have a consistent behaviour when *[ ]-indexing* a DataFrame as well as a Series. Remember that `df[1]` does not return the column located at the second position of that DataFrame and will trigger a `KeyError` (unless the literal 0 is an actual column and in this case, the column `0` will be returned).

---

So based on your code, your `df` (*see how I imagine it below*) most likely hasn't a default index (*i.e a range of
integers or at least a list of integers*). So when slicing each Series here `x[0]`, `x[1]` while the indices are strings `["A", "B", "C"]`, you're warned by pandas to use `x.iloc[0]` and `x.iloc[1]` instead.

```
my_columns_to_convert = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 4),
    index=list("ABC"), columns= my_columns_to_convert + ["colx"]
)

#    col1  col2  col3  colx
# A     0     3     6     3
# B    28    35    42     7
# C    88    99   110    11

def convert_my_data(value_1_in, value_2_in):
    return value_1_in * value_2_in # a simple calculation

for k in my_columns_to_convert:
    df[k] = (
        df[[k, "colx"]].apply(
            lambda x: convert_my_data(value_1_in=x[0], value_2_in=x[1]), axis=1)
    )

# the FutureWarning is displayed three times (= the length of the Series) :
```

> **FutureWarning**: `Series.__getitem__` treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`: `lambda x: convert_my_data(value_1_in=x[0], value_2_in=x[1]), axis=1)`

As a side note, your code seems to be not efficient and can potentially be easily vectorized.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Timeless' answer, you can avoid this warning by expanding the positional arguments (`*x`):

```
for k in my_columns_to_convert:
    df[k] = (
        df[[k, "colx"]].apply(
            lambda x: convert_my_data(*x), axis=1)
    )
```

Output:

```
# before
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  colx
A     0     1     2     3
B     4     5     6     7
C     8     9    10    11

# after
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  colx
A     0     3     6     3
B    28    35    42     7
C    88    99   110    11
```