# Extract array value using index stored in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, warnings

I have a numpy array:

```
np.random.seed(123456)
a=np.random.randint(0,9, (5,5))

array([[1, 2, 1, 8, 0],
       [7, 4, 8, 4, 2],
       [6, 6, 7, 2, 6],
       [2, 4, 4, 7, 4],
       [4, 4, 5, 1, 7]])
```

and a pandas dataframe with the indices where I would like the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]],columns=['i','j'])
```

In the past I used:

```
df['vals'] = df[['i', 'j']].apply(lambda x: a[x[0], x[1]], axis=1)

   i  j  vals
0  0  1     2
1  1  2     8
2  2  3     2
```

Which gives me the values I want (2, 8, 2) but has started giving me the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Series.**getitem**
> treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer
> keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame
> behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
> df['vals'] = df[['i', 'j']].apply(lambda x: a[x[0], x[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106980/pandas-2-1-0-futurewarning-series-getitem-treating-keys-as-positions-is-dep)], axis=1)

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106980/pandas-2-1-0-futurewarning-series-getitem-treating-keys-as-positions-is-dep) tried using `df.loc[:, 'vals'] = df.loc[:,['i', 'j']].apply(lambda x: d[x[0], x[1]], axis=1)` but I still get the warning. Also as suggested I tried using `df['vals'] = df[['i', 'j']].apply(lambda x: a[*x], axis=1)` but I get a syntax error

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? I don't like to silence warnings because I usually learn something from them.

Comment: Does work without warning? `a[df['i'],df['j']]`

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, not sure how I missed that... it seems so obvious!!

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing what the linked Q/A suggests.

Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or a [starred expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-starred_expression) actually *turns-off* the `FutureWarning` :

```
# Timeless
df["vals"] = df[["i", "j"]].apply(lambda x: a[x.iloc[0], x.iloc[1]], axis=1)

# Corralien
df["vals"] = df[["i", "j"]].apply(lambda x: a[(..., *x)], axis=1) # or a[(*x,)]
```

You can even stick with your approach and simply subtitute `0/1` with `i/j` :

```
df["vals"] = df[["i", "j"]].apply(lambda x: a[x["i"], x["j"]], axis=1)
# because `x` is a Series with length of 2 and i/j as indices
```

But FWIW, in your context, you should use numpy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) :

```
# hpaulj
df["vals"] = a[df["i"], df["j"]]
```

Output :

```
   i  j  vals
0  0  1     2
1  1  2     8
2  2  3     2

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Correct, I am not using iloc because the setup requires column names (i.e., loc). Not sure how I missed numpy's advanced indexing, guess I'm just dumb like that!